# How to merge two csv files not including duplicates

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk, grep

If I have a csv files like this

```
lion@mammal@scary animal
human@mammal@human
hummingbird@bird@can fly
dog@mammal@man's best friend
cat@mammal@purrs a lot
shark@fish@very scary
fish@fish@blub blub
```

and I have another csv file like this

```
cat@mammal@purrs a lot
shark@fish@very scary
fish@fish@blub blub
rockets@pewpew@fire
banana@fruit@yellow
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
lion@mammal@scary animal
human@mammal@human
hummingbird@bird@can fly
dog@mammal@man's best friend
cat@mammal@purrs a lot
shark@fish@very scary
fish@fish@blub blub
rockets@pewpew@fire
banana@fruit@yellow
```

some of the things in the first csv file are present in the second csv file; they overlap pretty much. How can I combine these csv files with the correct order? It is guaranteed that the new entries will always be the first few lines in the beginning of the first csv file.

Comment: Are you fine if the output is sorted on alphabetical order?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Soultion 1:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file1.cvs file2.cvs
```

Solution 2 (if don't care of the original order)

```
sort -u file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

- Use `cat -n` to concatenate input files and prepend line numbers
- Use `sort -u` remove duplicate data
- Use `sort -n` to sort again by prepended number
- Use `cut` to remove the line numbering

```
$ cat -n file1 file2 | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2-
lion@mammal@scary animal
human@mammal@human
hummingbird@bird@can fly
dog@mammal@man's best friend
cat@mammal@purrs a lot
shark@fish@very scary
fish@fish@blub blub
rockets@pewpew@fire
banana@fruit@yellow
$
```

Comment: Useless Use of Cat Award (http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: @BMW - why?  How would you concatenate the files *and* add line numbers?

Comment: @BMW - Perhaps you are referring to the first two cat invocations here.  Actually these are simply for demonstration purposes to show what the contents of the input files are, before processing.  I guess this extra output detracts from the answer and is not really necessary, so I'll remove them